# Excel formula to check if values from a comma separated list in one cell equal to value of other columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet where every row has 6 columns, each containing a comma separated list of words or phrases.

| column 1 | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A,C |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| A,B,E |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| D,F |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I'm trying to create a formula that checks if the values in column 1 is equal to column 2, If so give the output as 1, if not give it as 0. Output should look like the table below.

| column 1 | A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A,C | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| A,B,E | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| D,F | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use find(), iferror() and if() like so:

[image]

To save you typing too much:

```
IF(IFERROR(FIND(B$1,$A2,1),0)>0,1,0)
```